# How to find numbers $k$ such that $kx - \ln(ex + 1-x) $ is positive on $(0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

I want to find a condition on $k$ such that $g(x)= kx - \ln(ex + 1-x) > 0$, $x\in [0,1] $.

At zero the function is zero.

So, to find a condition on $k$ I use $g'(x) > 0$ i.e.

$$ k > \frac{e-1}{ex + 1 -x}$$

Now if I put $x=0.5$, then $k > \frac{2(e-1)}{e + 1 }$

let $k = 0.95$ as it satisfies the condition. But, I see that with this $k$, $g(0.5) <0$. I am making some silly mistake but not finding where.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do @user148951?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: I said that in the first line.

Comment: From a [WolframAlpha inequality plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kx+-+log%28ex+%2B+1+-+x%29+%3E+0%2C+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+1), it looks like $k \geq 1$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: yes, you are correct. that also follows from Jensen's inequality. But, what is wrong in my above argument ?

Comment: You want $g^\prime(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, but what you in fact do by choosing $x=0.5$ is enforcing that $g^\prime(0.5)>0$. You should take the largest value possible on the right-hand side of your inequality, which is for $x=0$. This will give $k>e-1$. However, this will satisfy your condition, but will not give you the optimal value. This should be done in the way proposed by Claude Leibovici.

Comment: @SPK : understood my mistake.

Comment: We can make this simpler : notice that $g''(x)$ is positive for any $x$. So, it could be sufficient to set $k$ is such a way that $g'(0)>0$ that is to say $1-e+k>0$ that is to say $k>e-1$. What do you think about that ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici :  As SPK said that does not give optimal $k$. so, the below answer have to be used as you have said.

Comment: I think that what I wrote in my previous comment is just good sense. When you first complained, this forced me to think more and I thank you for that. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : I am deleting this question as it is not any general one, it was my personal mistake and also does not contain much information. If possible delete the answer please.

Comment: @user148951 It is possible to actually delete it, there is a button below the tags next to the vote count :)

Comment: Don't delete it, please. Even if you made a mistake, the problem is interesting ! I suppose that you would have not ask the question if no mistake. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I understand. But, sometimes back some moderators asked me to delete personal doubt/mistakes from the sites. They also sometimes downvote for that. I don't want to loose reputation !!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because sometimes back some moderators asked me to delete personal doubt/mistakes from the sites. They also sometimes downvote for that. I don't want to loose reputation !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

In order $$g(x)= kx - \ln(ex + 1-x) > 0, x\in [0,1]$$ k must be such that for no $x$ in the interval $g(x)$ could be negative.

So, first look where is located the extremum (corresponding to $g'(x)=0$), use the second derivative test to know nif it is a maximum of a minimum. If it is a minimum, express the value of $g(x_*)$ (corresponding to $g'(x_*)=0$) and find the condition for $k$.

I am sure that you can take from here. I hope and wish that you understand the reasonning; if not, just post?

Comment: I agree. The function must be strictly increasing.